# How to remove setup partition ( volume ) after OS install

Tags: partitioning, diskpart

I was installing a new Windows on my new SSD from a USB drive but the often appearing error "We couldn't create a new partition or bla bla.." appeared so I used cmd and diskpart to create a new 5GB volume on my SSD, copied the installation files there and ran the installation again from that partition.

It worked, I installed the OS, everything works fine... except...
That partition where the OS installation files are is still there, I want to remove it but it seems that it's not that simple.

It is marked as "active" and "system" in the Windows drive format tool. ( picture below )

[image: disks]

I tried marking my C disk where the OS actually is installed as active but then Windows can't boot anymore. Also when my PC boots it shows me an annoying screen where I can choose to enter Windows 10 or go to Windows setup again ( obviously booting the installation again from that volume ).

How the hell do I get rid of this thing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the small partition, as it is now the one that is used for booting
Windows.

Originally Windows gave that error message because you have apparently already
created a partition that spanned the entire disk.

It is possible to specify an existing partition for the installation.
Not doing so requires Windows to create a new partition using the unallocated
space on the disk, of which you had none available.

Removing the partition will require the re-installation of Windows, during
which you should delete all partitions, leave the disk entirely as unallocated
space, so Windows can freely allocate its own partition
(as long as you click and select that unallocated space during the installation).

It is also good practice to connect the future boot disk as disk number 0.
To avoid problems, it is also better to disconnect the other disk
while installing Windows from a boot CD/USB.

Comment: I don't think  I understand what you mean by " already created a partition that spanned the entire disk." I didn't just create a partition out of unallocated space, I tried doing it both ways but it didn't matter, same error both ways.

Comment: Try to redo it as described above. It might have been a confusion between the two disks, which is why it's better to keep things simple with only one disk that is all unallocated space.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it but first you need to both mark C active and transfer the boot files using **bcdboot**

> BCDBoot copies the boot files to either the active partition on the primary hard drive, or the partition specified by the /s option.
>   BCDBoot creates the BCD store in the same partition.

See [bcdboot command line options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di) for details.

In your case therefore, sign into Windows and set small partition inactive and C active in Disk Management.  Then go to administrator command prompt and enter

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f ALL
```

Reboot and if all is OK and small partition is not market 'System' or 'Boot' you can delete it.

If you like you can then move C to the left hand side of your disk using a tool like [Minitool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html).